# Making autocomplete extender in ASP.NET

Tags: c#

I have a textbox. I'm fetching data from the database through autocomplete functionality, but the problem is I'm getting more than 200 records as the result. I want to display only 10 records in autocomplete list based on search and I want to display a more link like `More >>` just below the 10 records. When the user clicks on `More >>` link it will display 10 new records in autocomplete list based on user search.

Comment: I think you would have to write a custom control (inherited from AutoCompleteExtender) for this...

Comment: @naveed butt, but how do i achieve this functionality,if u have any idea plz guide me to do

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a custom control to modify the functionality of the `AutoCompleteExtender`. You will have to customize the render event and will have to render a link of `more` after `n` number of rows.

Here is a tutorial on how to write a custom control for `AutoCompleteExtender`, although this tutorial does something else, but you can have a basic idea of how to write a custom control.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/CustomAutoCompleteExt.aspx